# Creating a vector of non-copyable objects

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

I am using [DenseCRF](http://www.philkr.net/code) library and I wanted to generate a vector of the this object class, but I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:108:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘DenseCRF::DenseCRF(const DenseCRF&)’
/densecrf2/include/densecrf.h:48:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const DenseCRF’ to ‘DenseCRF&’
```

This is what class DenseCRF.h looks like:

```
/**** DenseCRF ****/
class DenseCRF{
protected:
    // Number of variables and labels
    int N_, M_;

    // Store the unary term
    UnaryEnergy * unary_;

    // Store all pairwise potentials
    std::vector<PairwisePotential*> pairwise_;

    // Don't copy this object, bad stuff will happen
    DenseCRF( DenseCRF & o ){}
public:
    // Create a dense CRF model of size N with M labels
    DenseCRF( int N, int M );
    virtual ~DenseCRF();

}
```

This is the refined version of denseCRF.h and the error that indicates a problem with denseCRF.h:48, refers to line 14 in this code snippet:

```
DenseCRF( DenseCRF & o ){}
```

In the main program, I am trying to create a vector of this class, but once I want to puch_back an  object instance, it raises the above error:

```
std::vector<DenseCRF> crf_vec;
DenseCRF crf(W, H);
crf_vec.push_back(crf);
```

I googled a bit and realized that I may need to define a copy constructor, but not sure how and where. Could anybody help me with this problem?

Thank you!

P.S. Does this issue have anything to do with the comments of the authors in line.13?

Comment: A `std::vector<T>` needs `T` to provide a proper copy constructor as mentioned in the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that requirement was relaxed in C++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the *easiest* thing to do will be to define

`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DenseCRF>> crf_vec;`

instead. Then use

`crf_vec.push_back(new DenseCRF(W, H));`

`std::shared_ptr` is a *smart pointer*. It will `delete` the class once the vector goes out of scope and all other smart pointers referring to the object are also out of scope. The advantage of this approach is that `std::shared_ptr` *does* have a copy constructor so can be used in a `std::vector`.

There is an alternative: using *emplacement*. But that's trickier.

(Also, you can replace `DenseCRF( DenseCRF & o ){}` with `DenseCRF(DenseCRF&) = delete;`. This is an explicit *deletion* of the copy constructor.)

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to use std::shared_ptr by including <memory>,  it raises the error that "std::shared_ptr" was not declared in this scope.

Comment: you can try std::tr1::shared_ptr< ... > or add -std=c++11 to compiler

Comment: @user3517598 Are you using GCC 4.6? Make sure to specify `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @Sergey `std::shared_ptr` should be preferred over the `tr1` version. The flag `c++11` doesn't exist in 4.6. It's `c++0x`.

Comment: Sorry, but after making these changes, now I am getting this error: '/densecrf2/examples/dense_learning_default.cpp:188:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DenseCRF> >::push_back(DenseCRF*)’'.

Comment: @user3517598 `std::make_shared<DenseCRF>(1, 2)`